# In Woocommerce I want to add my custom payment gateway code along with Cheque payment

Tags: woocommerce, payment-gateway

I need to integrate a payment gateway in woocommerce. I have installed a custom payment gateway plugin. But I didn't find the option for integration of the code.

I tried to add code on the thankyou.php. Here,
1. I am checking the payment method selected.
2. If my custom payment is selected it redirects to payment-gateway.php file, it contains my PG code.

But when I am redirected to thankyou.php the order entry is made in database and email is send to admin before payment made.

How can I avoid this? Or is there any other way to integrate my PG code.

Comment: what code are we talking here? coupon code? I doubt, so what?

Comment: php code regarding my payment gateway.

Comment: can you include it in this post?

Comment: The pg php-code works fine with all the order details and payment. I need help for executing this code at right place. for example - If user selects my PG option on checkout page. I want to redirect him to my paymentgateway.php file. How can i do this?